# jQuery on click remove input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

one more question.

This is the website: http: //www.revewit.com/

Check out input field on the left, it 's the work of jQueryUI autocomplete. What I want to do is place a placeholder, text which will disappear after I click the input field, and I can't find a way to do it. This is the code I have for now:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > (function(jQuery) {
jQuery.widget("ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var input, self = this,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children(":selected"),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "ppp",
            wrapper = this.wrapper = jQuery("<span>").addClass("ui-combobox").insertAfter(select);

        input = jQuery("<input>").appendTo(wrapper).val(value).addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp(jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                    var text = jQuery(this).text();
                    if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) return {
                        label: text.replace(
                        new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };

                }));
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                document.location.href = ui.item.option.value;
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                self._trigger("selected", event, {
                    item: ui.item.option
                });
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(jQuery(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                        valid = false;
                    select.children("option").each(function() {
                        if (jQuery(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!valid) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        jQuery(this).val("");
                        select.val("");
                        input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

        input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return jQuery("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);

        };

        jQuery("<a>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Show All Items").appendTo(wrapper).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle").click(function() {
            // close if already visible
            if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                input.autocomplete("close");
                return;
            }

            // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
            jQuery(this).blur();

            // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete("search", "");
            input.focus();
        });
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
        jQuery.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
 });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#combobox").combobox();
jQuery("#toggle").click(function() {
    jQuery("#combobox").toggle();
});
});

< /script>​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browser can do this out of the box:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="foo"/>
```

For older browsers you can use this [polyfill](https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill)

**EDIT**

Sure you can do this in jQuery, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/qcYNE/):

```
$('<input/>').attr('placeholder', 'test').appendTo('body')
```

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is, input field is generated via jQuery, and I don't know how to implement placeholder with jQuery :/

Comment: can you do `attr('placeholder','foo')` or `prop('placeholder','foo')` (forget which one is right) while instantiating?

Comment: @user1356223 See the example I added

Comment: Thank you guys, I don't have access now to backend, will try code later today and give you result, thank you!